# Using McNemar’s test to compare binary classifiers

Tags: classification, paired-data, model-comparison

I am evaluating multiple ML models which are performing the same binary classification task on the same dataset with the same train-val-test split. I am now looking to compare these models and since the splits are the same  my research suggest I need to use a paired test such as McNemar’s test. Now if I have understood it correctly this test looks at how the model classifies each individual entry in the test set creating a matrix like so:

|  | Yes | No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | Yes/Yes | Yes/No |
| No | No/Yes | No/No |

however doesn't this not take into account whether the predictions are actually correct, just what the model predicted? Or is my base assumption wrong about how the test functions in this case?

Comment: I would guess that the categories you want on your table margins are not 'yes' and 'no' but 'correct' and 'incorrect' classification.  The McNemar test is then a test whether one model classifies more individuals correctly than the other.    Whether classification accuracy should be your goal is a separate question.

Comment: Alright so the McNemars in this case would be based on the confusion matrices and not on the individual classifications, that makes more sense. I am also using other metrics as goals. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not knowing the context for the question, I still strongly suspect that [classification is not appropriate for the task at hand](https://fharrell.com/post/classification).

Comment: @FrankHarrell very interesting, and new to me, as I am also new to this field. Funnily enough this is also medical research and statistics which seems to be you area of expertise. The purpose is to determine whether or not a patient has an elevated biomarker based on an ECG as input. If I am reading your blog right this would then be labeled a binary prediction instead as it would still be the physicians choice to do further testing etc? Or would it be a classifier as it is not a decision to make if the biomarker is elevated or not, but the decision rather lies in what to do with the outcome?

Comment: The simple answer is that the decision maker needs to have all available information to make a good decision.  That information includes estimated probabilities, not whether the probability exceeds some point.  Think of a car whose speedometer reads "slow" and "fast" as an example of premature dichotomization.    But for your problem it may go a little deeper than that because it is probably more appropriate to predict the continuous biomarker level from the ECG.  Then you can get a predicted mean and a predicted individual biomarker (these may be equal) continuous value.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Very helpful. We considered a continuous readout, however in reality the biomarker is used in a binary fashion as being above or below cutoff which is why we started there, with the intention to, when we have more data, make a continuous prediction. Thank you for the help, this will be excellent for my discussion and further research. :)